# Using primitives or wrapper class in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, mapping, double, primitive

Mapping database with Hibernate.

We should use Double with @NotNull constraint
Or use the double primitive type instead.
What is the best practice? (Using Java 6)

```
@Column(name = "price_after_tax", nullable=false)
@NotNull
public Double getPriceAfterTax() {
    return priceAfterTax;
}
```

OR

```
@Column(name = "price_after_tax")
public double getPriceAfterTax() {
    return priceAfterTax;
}
```

Many thanks!

Comment: I cannot refrain from commenting that `BigDecimal` (though a pain in use) would be a better choice. And in the database DECIMALS instead of DOUBLE. As double introduces small errors.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you should use `Double` as it can hold even null value. So, in future if by any chance you decides make the DB column null-able, then you are safe. You just need to remove the `@NotNull'. You can not use the primitive`double` in this condition.

In any case hibernate is Object Relational Mapping, I would always stick to using Objects in my entity beans. It's a debatable point through.

There is even a logical issue with the primitives, say you don't know or don't have a value for `priceAfterTax`. If you use the primitive, the default value will be always there `0.0`. Which says that **there is no tax!**. But when I use `Double` it has `null` by defaults means **I don't know what the tax is.**