# Null object if entity not found

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm working with Hibernate and JPA. I have an entity called `Customer` that references a `ParentCustomer`:

```
public class Customer {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "CustomerID")
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ParentCustomerID")
    private Customer parent;

    // ...
}
```

But in my db there are some customers that have no parent so the `ParentCustomerID` is set to `0`. The exception I get when I test my class is:

`javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find it.keyforup.pat.data.entities.Customer with id 0`

Is there a way to set the `ParentCustomer` to `null` when id is `0`?

Comment: why you say 0? If you want the entity to be `null`, then the foreign key value should be `null`.

Comment: I'm working on a db used by a third party application, this application set the parent id to 0 when there is no parent for a customer... so I would make sure that every time the parent is not found the `parent` property is set to null.

Comment: However this is not legitimate database behaviour. Furthermore if strict database restriction validation was implied they couldn't even do that..

Comment: I assume that u are using the key column **primitive** type and that's why **0** gets inserted instead of **NULL** It is not such good idea as told http://stackoverflow.com/q/10110081/507864.

Comment: Exact duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4676594/hibernate-many-to-one-foreign-key-default-0

Comment: @ManuPK Is there such thing as primitive type in sql?

Comment: @BorisStrandjev: I was referring to the **bean mapping** in Java.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try this

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "ParentCustomerID")
@NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
private Customer parent;
```

Comment: This was suggested in the exact duplicate I posted.

Comment: As it happends, I've had this issue in the past and resolved with the notfound annotation, so when I saw the thread - it was kind of been on a treadmill - decided to post the answer straight away before someone beat me to it. Didn't see the duplicate post at first hand- Good call.

Comment: There is an edge case when you need LAZY fetch. Hibernate's `@NotFound` annotation just ignores `fetch = FetchType.LAZY` in `@ManyToOne` annotation. Just check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38097248/hibernate-lazy-loading-issue.