# Hibernate Lazy Loading Issue

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, lazy-loading

I mapped this entity in Hibernate 5

```
class A {
    private String code;
    private B child;

    @LazyToOne(LazyToOneOption.PROXY)
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @NotFound(action=NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    @JoinColumns({...})
    public B getChild() { ... }
}
```

And my query to load **only A** is:

```
from A where a.code like :q
```

With this configuration Hibernate makes a select on A and on B entities.
I don't want it to load B but only A

What am I missing?

Comment: Is that really the entire class?  This technique only works if hibernate can generate a proxy for the class, but other contents of your class (like a nondefault constructor, or it being final) could prevent hibernate from generating a proxy.

Comment: This is all class. https://gist.github.com/stefanopulze/c921cf477c6713feee3f79e42a51fef6

Comment: Consider using entity JPA 2.1 entity graphs: http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-21-entity-graph-part-1-named-entity/

Comment: Do you really need the NotFound? My guess is that this is the cause of your problem: you're basically saying Hibernate: my schema is a mess, and although table A has a column containing the ID of a B, that B might not exist. So Hibernate needs to select from B to know if that B exists or not. Fix your data, add a foreign key constraint, remove the NotFound, and it shouldn't load from B anymore.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem, which is caused by Hibernate ignoring the FetchType.LAZY, if NotFoundAction.IGNORE is defined.

After some googling I found a workaround:
http://chekkal.blogspot.com/2012/09/hibernate-lazy-loading-and-notfound.html

```
public FieldType getField() {
    if(!Hibernate.isInitialized(field)) {
        try {
            Hibernate.initialize(field);
        }catch(EntityNotFoundException one) {
            field=null;
        }
    }
    return field;
}
```

In Hibernate 5.4.2 the exception has changed to EntityNotFoundException, but this workaround seems to work for me.

Comment: Is this approach really faster than FetchType.EAGER and NotFoundAction.IGNORE?

Comment: Well, I don't think it's faster than FetchType.EAGER, when you access the field. But with the concept of lazy loading you can load data only when/if it is needed. Especially in big entity classes with several relationships, you might not want to load all relating objects by default, but only when required.