# Spring Hibernate reference ID return "null value"

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Help!, I've been trying to resolved this but I can't get the value of the referenced id, it returns a null value when saving.

```
Error: Column 'p_id' cannot be null
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Column 'p_id' cannot be null
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:74)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81)
    at $Proxy23.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2870)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3381)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:362)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:203)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:183)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:320)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:287)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:193)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:151)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:831)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:824)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingAction$7.cascade(CascadingAction.java:315)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:380)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:323)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:409)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:350)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:326)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:165)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeAfterSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:448)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:293)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:193)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:151)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:78)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:840)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:815)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:819)
    at nhtu.dao.UserDAOImpl.addPerson(UserDAOImpl.java:43)
    at nhtu.controller.ApplicantForm.update(ApplicantForm.java:70)
    at nhtu.controller.ApplicantForm.create(ApplicantForm.java:59)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:436)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:424)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1001)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'p_id' cannot be null
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1040)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4074)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4006)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2468)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2629)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2719)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2155)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2450)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2371)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2355)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:105)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:105)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:122)
    ... 70 more
```

This are my Models

```
@Entity
@Table(name="personal_info")
public class Person {


@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="p_id")
private int personId;

@Column(name="l_name")
private String lastName;

@Column(name="f_name")
private String firstName;

@Column(name="m_name")
private String middleName;

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name="b_date")
private Date birthDate;

private String address;

@Column(name="gender")
private String gender;

@Column(name="ext_name")
private String nameExtension;

@Column(name="marital_status")
private String maritalStatus;

@Column(name="c_num")
private String contactNumber;

@Column(name="email")
private String emailAddress;

@Column(name="coll_grad")
private int isCollegeGraduate;

@Column(name="post_grad")
private int isPostGraduate;

@Column(name="undergrad")
private int isUnderGraduate;

@OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL}, mappedBy="person")
private Collection<Application> application  = new ArrayList<Application>(); //                 
    link to applications

@OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST},mappedBy="personId")
private Collection<EducationalDetails> educationalDetail = new    
    ArrayList<EducationalDetails>(); // link to educational attainments of a person

public Collection<EducationalDetails> getEducationalDetails(){
    return educationalDetail;
}

public void setEducationalDetails(Collection<EducationalDetails> educationalDetail)     
    {
    this.educationalDetail=educationalDetail;
}

public int getPersonId() {
    return personId;
}
public void setPersonId(int personId) {
    this.personId = personId;
}

@OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL}, mappedBy="person")
private Collection<Employment> employment = new ArrayList<Employment>(); // link to                     
    employee

public Person() {}



public int getIsCollegeGraduate() {
    return isCollegeGraduate;
}
public void setIsCollegeGraduate(int isCollegeGraduate) {
    this.isCollegeGraduate = isCollegeGraduate;
}
public int getIsPostGraduate() {
    return isPostGraduate;
}
public void setIsPostGraduate(int isPostGraduate) {
    this.isPostGraduate = isPostGraduate;
}
public int getIsUnderGraduate() {
    return isUnderGraduate;
}
public void setIsUnderGraduate(int isUnderGraduate) {
    this.isUnderGraduate = isUnderGraduate;
}
public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}
public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}
public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}
public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}
public String getMiddleName() {
    return middleName;
}
public void setMiddleName(String middleName) {
    this.middleName = middleName;
}
public Date getBirthDate() {
    return birthDate;
}
public void setBirthDate(Date birthDate) {
    this.birthDate = birthDate;
}
public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}
public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}
public String getGender() {
    return gender;
}
public void setGender(String gender) {
    this.gender = gender;
}
public String getNameExtension() {
    return nameExtension;
}
public void setNameExtension(String nameExtension) {
    this.nameExtension = nameExtension;
}
public String getMaritalStatus() {
    return maritalStatus;
}
public void setMaritalStatus(String maritalStatus) {
    this.maritalStatus = maritalStatus;
}
public String getContactNumber() {
    return contactNumber;
}
public void setContactNumber(String contactNumber) {
    this.contactNumber = contactNumber;
}
public String getEmailAddress() {
    return emailAddress;
}
public void setEmailAddress(String emailAddress) {
    this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
}
public Collection<Application> getApplication() {
    return application;
}
public void setApplication(Collection<Application> application) {
    this.application = application;
}

public Collection<EducationalDetails> getEducationalDetail() {
    return educationalDetail;
}
public void setEducationalDetail(
        Collection<EducationalDetails> educationalDetail) {
    this.educationalDetail = educationalDetail;
}
public Collection<Employment> getEmployment() {
    return employment;
}
public void setEmployment(Collection<Employment> employment) {
    this.employment = employment;
}
    }

    @Entity
    @Table(name="educ_detail")
    public class EducationalDetails {

@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="ed_id")
private int educDetailsId;

@ManyToOne(targetEntity=Person.class)
@JoinColumn(name ="p_id",referencedColumnName="p_id")
private Person personId;

@Column(name="level")
private int educationalLevel;

@Column(name="name_school")
private String nameOfSchool;

@Column(name="inc_date")
private String inclusiveDates;

@Column(name="course")
private String course;

@Column(name="year_graduated")
private int yearGraduated;

@Column(name="units_earned")
private int unitsEarned;

public EducationalDetails(){}

/*public EducationalDetails(Person person){
    this.person = person;

}*/

public int getEducDetailsId() {
    return educDetailsId;
}

public void setEducDetailsId(int educDetailsId) {
    this.educDetailsId = educDetailsId;
}

public int getEducationalLevel() {
    return educationalLevel;
}

public void setEducationalLevel(int educationalLevel) {
    this.educationalLevel = educationalLevel;
}

public String getNameOfSchool() {
    return nameOfSchool;
}

public void setNameOfSchool(String nameOfSchool) {
    this.nameOfSchool = nameOfSchool;
}

public String getInclusiveDates() {
    return inclusiveDates;
}

public void setInclusiveDates(String inclusiveDates) {
    this.inclusiveDates = inclusiveDates;
}

public String getCourse() {
    return course;
}

public void setCourse(String course) {
    this.course = course;
}

public int getYearGraduated() {
    return yearGraduated;
}

public void setYearGraduated(int yearGraduated) {
    this.yearGraduated = yearGraduated;
}

public int getUnitsEarned() {
    return unitsEarned;
}

public void setUnitsEarned(int unitsEarned) {
    this.unitsEarned = unitsEarned;
}


public Person getPersonId(){
    return personId;

}

public void setPersonId(Person personId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    this.personId = personId;
}

    }


    @Controller
    @RequestMapping("/applicantForm.html")
    public class ApplicantForm {


@Autowired
    private UserDAO userdao;
//private EducationalDetails educDetail  = new EducationalDetails();
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder dataBinder) {
    System.out.println("dataBinder");
    dataBinder.setRequiredFields(new String[] { "firstName", "lastName",             
            "middleName", "address", "gender" });
    dataBinder.registerCustomEditor(String.class, new   
    StringTrimmerEditor(false));
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Person setUpForm(@RequestParam(value = "id", required = false) Integer   
    personID) {
    System.out.println("setup form");
    if (personID == null) {
        Person person = new Person();
        EducationalDetails educ1 = new EducationalDetails();
        EducationalDetails educ2 = new EducationalDetails();
        EducationalDetails educ3 = new EducationalDetails();    
        System.out.println(person.getLastName());
        person.getEducationalDetail().add(educ1);
        person.getEducationalDetail().add(educ2);
        person.getEducationalDetail().add(educ3);
        educ3.setPersonId(person);
        educ2.setPersonId(person);
        educ1.setPersonId(person);
        return person;
    } else {
        return userdao.getPersonById(personID);
    }
}

@RequestMapping(params = "create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String create(Person person, BindingResult result,
        SessionStatus status) {
    System.out.println("create");
    return update(person,result, status);
}

@RequestMapping(params = "update", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String update(Person person,BindingResult result, SessionStatus status) {
    //employeeValidator.validate(emp, result);
    System.out.println("update");
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        System.out.println("has errors");
        return "applicantForm";
    } else {
        userdao.addPerson(person);
        status.setComplete();
        return "redirect:applicantForm.html";
    }

}

   }

   @Repository
   public class UserDAOImpl implements UserDAO {

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}

public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
}

public Person addPerson(Person person) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    System.out.println(session);
    try {

        session.beginTransaction();
        session.persist(person);
        session.getTransaction().commit();

    } catch (HibernateException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        session.getTransaction().rollback();
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
      return person;


}


    public interface UserDAO {     

public Person addPerson(Person person);
public void modifyPersonDetails(int personId, String lastName, String firstName,            
    String middleName, String nameExtension,
        Date birthDate, String address, String gender, String        
    maritalStatus, String contactNumber, String emailAddress, 
        boolean isCollegeGraduate, boolean isPostGraduate, boolean   
     isUnderGraduate);
public Collection<Person> listAllPersons();
public Collection<Person> searchByName(String firstName, String lastName);
```

Comment: Which is the database used? Also can you enable the hibernate property `hibernate.show.sql=true`

Comment: Another suggestion, why don't you use spring transaction management instead of managing transaction management(commit/rolback) yourself

Answer (score 0):

The person object that is created in method below, is newly created by Spring MVC framework, please check its "educationalDetail" property and ensure that it is valid in terms of it pointing back to the parent "person" object

```
@RequestMapping(params = "create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String create(Person person, BindingResult result,
        SessionStatus status) {
    System.out.println("create");
    return update(person,result, status);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using a primitive `int`. Instead, you should use `Integer`.
Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10110281/1300817) to see why.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "p_id", unique = true, nullable = false)

private Integer personId;

public Integer getPersonId() {
    return this.id;
}

public setPersonId(Integer personId) {
    this.personId = personId;
}
```

Comment: This is not true. An id field can be a primitive field or a wrapper field. Maybe you should explain a bit more why using a wrapper type should be a solution in this case. What reasoning is behind it?